# python script doesn't stop with sys.exit()

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

In my Program I have a GUI with a progressbar. The value of the progressbar is a variable of a other script so I created an update function that refreshes the GUI so I have a moving progressbar.

```
def update(lblhowfar,bar,window,Zeitraum,auswahl,testprogress):# update function to refresh the progress bar and the percentage label
    while rd.filtering_done==False:
        Progress=int(rd.Zähler/rd.Nenner)
        percent=Progress,"%","of","100","%"
        if testprogress < Progress:
            bar['value'] = Progress
            testprogress=Progress
            lblhowfar.config(text=percent)
        window.update()
        time.sleep(.1)
    if rd.filtering_done:# when RelevanteDaten.py is done
        while rd.appending:
            time.sleep(.5)
            continue
        bar['value'] = 100
        percent="100","%","of","100","%"
        lblhowfar.config(text=percent)
        lbl2=Label(window, text="Filtering done",font=("Helvetica Neue 55 Roman",15))
        lbl2.pack()
        window.update()
        RelevanteDaten=rd.RelevanteDaten# Import important data from RelevanteDaten.py
        Continue(RelevanteDaten,lbl2,lblhowfar,bar,window,Zeitraum,auswahl,)
    else:
        window.after(1,update(lblhowfar,bar,window,Zeitraum,auswahl,testprogress))
```

on the GUI I wanted to have a button that will shut down the program but when i execute the button, I get an error message.

```
def Destroy(window,):#shuts down the program
    plt.close(fig="all")
    window.destroy()
    sys.exit()
```

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1702, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "CheckTool.py", line 258, in <lambda>
    button1 = Button(window, text="Use", command=lambda:button_generate(window,checkVariableForCheckBoxList,Zeitraum,),font=("Helvetica Neue 55 Roman",20))
  File "CheckTool.py", line 290, in button_generate
    get_selected_boxes(checkVariableForCheckBoxList,window,Zeitraum,)
  File "CheckTool.py", line 299, in get_selected_boxes
    create_progress_bar(Zeitraum,auswahl,)
  File "CheckTool.py", line 446, in create_progress_bar
    progressscreen.after(1,update(lblhowfar,bar,window,Zeitraum,auswahl,testprogress))
  File "CheckTool.py", line 231, in update
    window.update()
  File "C:\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1174, in update
    self.tk.call('update')
_tkinter.TclError: can't invoke "update" command: application has been destroyed
```

so apparently the update function still runs although it should stop with sys.exit(). Right?

Already thank you for your help.

Kind regards

Comment: It is not a good idea use `sys.exit()` with a GUI application because it interferes with the shutdown process, as you have discovered. Instead, arrange for a widget to call `destroy()` on the root window. The framework will take care of calling `sys.exit()` at the proper moment. You may be thinking of `os._exit()` which messily shuts down the interpreter without calling cleanup handlers, flushing stdio buffers, etc. That is will do as you expect, but it is an even worse way to go about things.

Comment: when I only use the window.destroy() then the message appears because the update function is based on the window so it will still Show the message.

Comment: Then disable the update function before shutting down the application.

Comment: how can I disable the function? Is there sth. like update.stop()?

Comment: Your update function is linked to an event hook, right? Unlink it. Or set a flag in `Destroy` and have `update` bail out early if the flag is set.

Comment: @BoarGules Thanks that helped. I created a new flag that I Change by pressing the button. Now the Program shuts down without an error at any time.